# Is there any evidence that humans isolated from each other genetically are less able to produce viable offspring?

Tags: genetics, species

I would guess that before a new species originates, members of subgroups might have difficulty in interbreeding. Is this possible?

Comment: Humans as a species are very genetically homogenous, will little genetic diversity compared to our sister species. Basically there is so little human genetic diversity this would be all but impossible to test.

Comment: @John: As a practical test, American Indians and Europeans (Africans, too) were genetically isolated for at least 10K years - probably longer considering that the Indians' ancestors came from eastern Asia - yet there are plenty of us who are descended from both groups.  I understand the same practical test has been applied in Australia, too.

Comment: @jamesqf 10K years sounds like a lot but it really isn't especially when starting with low diversity. humans lave less genetic diversity than a single subspecies of chimpanzee. which have an order of magnitude more variation. https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2012/03/120302101706.htm and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_genetic_variation

Comment: @John: True, but as a practical answer to the question, we can only look at groups of humans that have been separated for various periods and see if they actually do have trouble interbreeding.  The American and Australian examples are the cases I can think of where groups of humans have been reproductively isolated for the longest periods.  Unless you include Neandertals, and I don't think there's enough data to say whether there were functional problems with interbreeding.

Comment: @jamesqf your issue will be American and Australian lines are fairly closely related. Most of human genetic diversity is in Africa. Australian and native American only diverged 70,000 years ago. If you want the longest isolation sub-Saharan African and South America would be your best bet. that will be at minimum 120,000 years of divergence, if not more. but you will run in to a big problem because human fertility rates vary drastically due to standard of living, by as much as 8 fold across all populations.

Comment: @John: But the question is not about genetic diversity, it's about reproductive isolation.  If you want to look at South American and SS-African, take the population of Brazil as your example.  I think you won't find any reproductive problems.  Fertility rates vs standard of living (however defined) is an entirely different question, one that gets into technology, culture, and individual choice, not simple biology.

Comment: @jamesqf I recognize fertility is a different question but it is a confounding to what we want to study, When you try to study cross fertilization your measurements are going to be swamped by other factors effecting fertility. Your study size would have to be absolutely massive to deal with this. this will confound reproductive isolations as well because so many places experienced colonization and establishing a lack of crossbreeding will be difficult to demonstrate for populations large enough for your needs.

Comment: @releseabe You will need to be more specific. Can you point to a specific source, or dataset, or other citation that you would like to know more about? Here is a non-technical description of reproductive isolation: https://www.sparknotes.com/biology/evolution/reproductiveisolation/section2/#:~:text=Hybrid%20Infertility,a%20horse%20with%20a%20donkey. Here is a more technical treatment: https://www.nature.com/scitable/topicpage/hybrid-incompatibility-and-speciation-820/

Comment: @MaximilianPress: i know that the Australian aborigines are a group that had been in isolation from other populations. i have never read that Europeans and this group can't have fertile offspring but i am wondering if there is any statistical effect: higher incidence of stillbirth or other issues.

Comment: @releseabe I'd suggest updating your question with that information specifically. Something like: "have human people of X group been separated from human people of Y group long enough to form reproductive incompatibilities?" I would suggest looking into this yourself also. I'm adding an answer but this may get more specific data.

Comment: @MaximilianPress: i think the question is clear and i dont want to limit it to two specific groups.

Comment: @John: Perhaps you're missing the point I have been trying to make, which is that the hypothesis of some human groups having difficulty reproducing with other groups due t genetic isolation (or indeed, anything else) has been disproven by experiment.

Comment: @jamesqf and my point is that any such experiment would likely be doomed to failure due to confounding factors. broad fertility is just too confounded by other fertility factors do do anything resembling a conclusive study. You would need hundreds of thousands of breeding pairs for just two groups to study isolated populations.

Comment: @John: But those "experiments" have been performed, naturally, when humans from long-isolated groups meet and have offspring.

Comment: @thats not the experiment the experiment is compiling that data and trying to calculate statistical significance. and if your confounding variables are powerful, you need a huge N to get useful calculation. An N that would have to be in the tens of thousands between just two isolated groups. (adding more groups would confounding and thus increase N) I don't know of any isolated groups that crossbreed in the hundreds of thousands with another group that is also considered isolated. Almost by definition if they are crossbreeding in those numbers they are not isolated.

Answer (score 3):

Studies looking into this [have not found any evidence of reproductive incompatibility in humans](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2016/01/160106092026.htm), at least not by the mechanisms other animals use.

Some [studies looking at co-variation of reproductive genes](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29340252/) find nominal positive associations between particular alleles within specific populations. This suggests (unsurprisingly) that there is functional variation of reproductive genes in humans, but again there is no evidence that it leads to the classic reproductive isolation case (e.g. [here](https://www.nature.com/scitable/topicpage/hybrid-incompatibility-and-speciation-820/)).

Some such co-occurring genetic variation of reproductive genes is [also observed across populations](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0002929710001448), but again if it's across human populations it is probably not doing a great job of isolating them.

In all of these situations, the statistical evidence seems to be rather weak. If these gene-gene associations are "real", they do not seem to be very strong at all or to have much effect on fertility, echoing comments from @John.